# Parametrize Auto Refresh for Superset Dashboard

Tags: real-time, apache-superset

My **Superset** Dashboard does **auto-refresh** but I wanted to **parameterize it**

Ex: http://192.168.223.16:8088/superset/dashboard/sample/?standalone=true&refreshTime=30

I found that we need to modify the DashBoard.jsx file but I am not able to locate where this file is.
I did search everything but dont know if this is hidden or something ?

Comment: As far as I can tell from a quick look at Superset code, this doesn't appear to be a feature. If you wanted to add it, you may want to start with calling [setRefreshFrequency](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/0.37/superset-frontend/src/dashboard/actions/dashboardState.js#L161) with the parameter from the url.

Answer (score 0):

DashBoard.jsx is under **incubator-superset/caravel/assets/javascripts** if you are using a clone version of apache-superset